# static content not working on virtual directories in IIS on XP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a strange problem with IIS on XP.

I have a ASP.MVC web application with a virtual directory pointing to it.

The application works OK, I see the generated html pages.
The problem is that I get 404 errors for all the static content files (css,js and image files).

The really strange thing is that if I create an application directly on the directory the static content is served, but I can't get the static content from a virtual directory pointing to the same directory!.

BTW, the static content is served OK from the virtual directory created by VS2010 for the application.

I can't find any differences in the configuration in the IIS between the virtual directory created by VS2010 (that works) and the one that does not work.

I anybody got any ideas, I would be VERY gratefull...

Thanks,

Nadav

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have hardcoded the url to those static files like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/foo.js"></script>
```

instead of using Url helpers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/foo.js")"></script>
```

which would of course account for the presence of the virtual directory and generate the proper url to this static file when the application is hosted inside a virtual directory:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myappname/scripts/foo.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, Actually I Do use @Url.Content() for all the static content.
And I see in Fiddler that URLs requested ARE OK.

Comment: Also, the problem also happens if I open the web site in the IIS admin tool (Control Panel/Administrative tools/Internet Infomation Services) and Click Browse on one of the static content files.
If the Application is a virtual directory I get 404, if the application is not a virtual directory the content is display.
This is definitely a problem in the configuration in the IIS and not in my application.